# how to pass the empty space in unique constraint column in oracle

Tags: talend

I want to pass empty space in not null(unique constraint)column.
Hence While trying to pass an (" ") into not null I am getting an error as ORA-00001 unique constraint violated.

(Note: using Talend for data transformation.)

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00001 unique constraint violated.

Seems like nothing to do with Talend Data Transformation. Check if you have already have a similar record.

Use TlogRow Component before the oracle component to log the insert values, if you wish to verify the information.